# Change OSX system font

Tags: macos, font

OS X Mountain Lion: Is there a way to change the default system font? 
Things like color (I'd like it slightly more gray) and the type.

EDIT:
And [Font Weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Weight), if possible.
Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is a duplicate question. I agree that the answer to both questions is the same software. But this question specifically asks about font color, type, and weight... while the other one asks about size.